# Android: Copiando um arquivo da pasta assets para o memória do celular

Tags: android

Estou fazendo um aplicativo, que em um botão que o usuário apertar, vai abrir um Arquivo PDF...

Aí está o problema, este arquivo se encontra na pasta Assets e eu desejo colocar ela na memória interna do Android...

O problema chega aí, o Android 7.0+ não está copiando...
Meu código atual:

```
    private void abrirCalendario() {
        AssetManager am = getAssets();
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;
        try {
            afd = am.openFd( "calendario_2017.pdf");

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + java.io.File.separator + "calendario_2017.pdf");
            file.createNewFile();

            copyFdToFile(afd.getFileDescriptor(), file);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(m, "Erro! Libere mais espaço no seu armazenamento!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Intent i = new Intent(Main.this, LeitorPDF.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    public static void copyFdToFile(FileDescriptor src, File dst) throws IOException {
        FileChannel inChannel = new FileInputStream(src).getChannel();
        FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream(dst).getChannel();
        try {
            inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
        } finally {
            if (inChannel != null)
                inChannel.close();
            if (outChannel != null)
                outChannel.close();
        }
    }
```

Está aí

Comment: Está tratando as Runtime Permissions em algum outro ponto do app? Ou é apenas isso?

Comment: É apenas isso, as permissoes estão tudo certas, nas versões anteriores a 7.0 do android roda certinho

Comment: Uma dúvida, como está acessando o arquivo na outra Activity? Ela é sua? Está passando alguma uri?

Comment: Desculpe ser repetitivo, mas quando perguntei sobre permissions, está tratando o pedido delas ou está apenas declarando no manifest?

Comment: A activity é minha, e ela simplesmente pega o arquivo desse mesmo caminho na memória e lê...
E as permissões estão na manifest

Comment: Hmm, precisa mesmo do arquivo no armazenamento externo? pq não lê diretamente dos assets na outra Activity? Sobre as permissões, a partir da versão 6.0, você além de definir no manifest, precisa ter a permissão do usuário para utilizar alguns recursos, recomendo dar uma olhada em: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html. Algumas permissões não precisam, mas External Storage é uma das permissões perigosas e que precisam de autorização do usuário.

Comment: precisa ser no armazenamento mesmo... Pois alem de usar na activity quero salvar no cartão